# Query with list comphrehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

I have list that looks like,

```
tmp_text = ['col1','','col2','col3','','']
```

I am trying to replace the empty elements in the list with an iterative value, this is the output I am trying to get

```
tmp_text = ['col1','Nan1','col2','col3','Nan2','Nan3']
```

Basically I need to replace the empty elements with the string 'NaN' but the with an iterative number attached to it. I need some help on how to do this.

Comment: Sure it could be done

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), which returns an iterator over numbers:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> tmp_text = ['col1','','col2','col3','','']
>>> counter = itertools.count(1)
>>> new_text = [x or f'Nan{next(counter)}' for x in tmp_text]
['col1', 'Nan1', 'col2', 'col3', 'Nan2', 'Nan3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [assignment/walrus](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) operator in python 3.8+ you can do this pretty easily

```
tmp_text = ['col1','','col2','col3','','']

i = 0
result = [x or f'Nan{(i:=i+1)}' for x in tmp_text]
```

---

```
['col1', 'Nan1', 'col2', 'col3', 'Nan2', 'Nan3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it

```
from itertools import counter
nan_counter = counter(1)

tmp_txt = [s if s else f'NaN{next(nan_counter)}' for s in tmp_txt]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this over list comprehension however? Each iteration you need to depend on a variable that will be conditionally updated.

However, there is still a way if you are doing python 3.8+ like so

```py
[x or f"Nan{(y := y + 1)}" for index, x in enumerate(tmp_text) if not index and (y := 0) or True]
```

Will give you

```py
['col1', 'Nan1', 'col2', 'col3', 'Nan2', 'Nan3']
```

I strongly advise against this as it is not really readable and has a questionable logic checking just to initialize a variable via walrus

Comment: The output should be `['col1','Nan1','col2','col3','Nan2','Nan3']`. Check yours again.

Comment: Thank you @ruohola that was a good catch on the `NaN` and the `Nan`, but yes it should output just that. I've updated the part within the f-string

Answer (score 0):

I've taken an example to execute this. Here for every empty element, we have to replace it by "Nan"+the number of empty element. So let's take a variable with i=1because first replacing would be "Nan1". We can put if condition, if the element is empty, replace it by "Nan"+str(i) where I has to be updated everytime. Try doing this:

```
l=['s','','d','','ht']
i=1
for j in range (len(l)):
    if l[j]=='':
        l[j]='Nan'+str(i)
        i+=1
    
print(l)
```